# A Better way? Finding ASP.NET controls, finding their id

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method that finds all the controls, iterates through them, determines if they are a textbox,drop down list, etc.. retrieves their ID name, and depending on the ID name it will set a boolean statement (thus I would know if that section of the form is complete, and will email to a certain group of people) unfortunetly this is done with too many if statements and was wondering if I could get some help making this more manageable

```
protected void getEmailGroup()
{
    Control[] allControls = FlattenHierachy(Page);
    foreach (Control control in allControls)
    {
        if (control.ID != null)
        {
            if (control is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox txt = control as TextBox;
                if (txt.Text != "")
                {
                    if (control.ID.StartsWith("GenInfo_"))
                    {
                        GenInfo = true;
                    }
                    if (control.ID.StartsWith("EmpInfo_"))
                    {
                        EmpInfo = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (control is DropDownList)
            {
                DropDownList lb = control as DropDownList;
                if (lb.SelectedIndex != -1)
                {
                    if (control.ID.StartsWith("GenInfo_"))
                    {
                        GenInfo = true;
                    }
                    if (control.ID.StartsWith("EmpInfo_"))
                    {
                        EmpInfo = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use wildcards in control names like that except *maybe* when developing a really messy custom control through compositing.

Comment: I am developing a really messy custom control heh.. I need to go through a form, determines if certain fields have been filled out, and by that determine who will receive only certain parts of the form.

Comment: maybe the problem statement could be rethought and thus control redesigned. You want to know which portions of a form are complete? Are you dynamically adding controls to your form? What defines a completed section of a form - the existence of a control with id=foo?

Comment: How do you fills the controls?? Also in your code once EmpInfo is true and GenInfo is true there is no point in continuing iterating..
And this not a lot of if statements..

Comment: The form has already been created. What defines a complete section of a form is if one the controls with a certain group name (GenInfo_) has a value.  If it does then I will send an email all of the General Information section to certain people.

Comment: gbianchi, you are correct about having no point to iterate any more. I heard breaking out of a method is bad coding?

Comment: And the data is stored somewhere else?

Comment: not as of yet, simply sent as email, though that would probably make this a bit easier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the Lambda expression I have created a method that handles the control for me, and depending on the name of the control, it sets that section to be true

```
public bool setGroup(Control ctrl)
    {
        isAControl = false;

        //set a section to true, so it will pull the html
        if (ctrl.ID.StartsWith("GenInfo_"))
        {
            GenInfo = true;
            lstControls.Add(ctrl.ID.Replace("GenInfo_", ""));
            isAControl = true;
            return isAControl;
        }
```

here is a small snippet of my code I only want to check for certain controls(to speed things up) and I go through each control as each control has a different way to get the value (textbox would use .text where dropdownlist would use .selectedValue)

```
if(control is TextBox || control is DropDownList || control is RadioButton || control is RadioButtonList 
                || control is CheckBox || control is CheckBoxList)
                {
                    if (control is TextBox)
                    {
                        TextBox txt = control as TextBox;
                        if (txt.Text != "" && txt.Text != "YYYY/MM/DD")
                        {
                            setGroup(control);
                            if (isAControl)
                            {
                                string controlNoGroup = lstControls.Last();
                                strHtml = strHtml.Replace("@" + (controlNoGroup.ToString()) + "@", txt.Text);
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: if anyone can improve on this let me know! works well, just like it to be efficient as possible

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the Control.FindControl(string) method?

> ```
> private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs MyEventArgs)
> {
>       // Find control on page.
>       Control myControl1 = FindControl("TextBox2");
>       if(myControl1!=null)
>       {
>          // Get control's parent.
>          Control myControl2 = myControl1.Parent;
>          Response.Write("Parent of the text box is : " + myControl2.ID);
>       }
>       else
>       {
>          Response.Write("Control not found");
>       }
> }
> ```

from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.control.findcontrol

Comment: I would usually use a findControl the only thing is I have over 100 controls (some textboxes, some radio, some drop down list) and I must go through them on to determine which ones have values in it, and from the determine who they will be sent to.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to understand the logic behind your code, but I'm sure it can be written easier. For example you can do something like this:

```
DropDownBox box = FlattenHierachy(Page)
   .Where(c => c is DropDownList)
   .Cast<DropDownList>()
   .Where(d => d.SelectedIndex != -1)
   .FirstOrDefault();
if (box != null)
{
   if (box.ID.StartsWith("GenInfo_"))
   {
      GenInfo = true;
   }
   if (box.ID.StartsWith("EmpInfo_"))
   {
       EmpInfo = true;
   }
}
```

Obviously you can make this generic if you extract the lambda expression from the seconde Where call. So you could reuse it for different types. That's the solution which is as close to your code as possible, but I guess it would be a better idea to use a recursive method traversing the page and giving that method your predicates as lambda expressions.

Comment: Excellent that seems to work well, I added a class so I don't have to keep typing in startsWith("controlName_")
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up you code a little to only include each check once.

```
protected void getEmailGroup()
    {
        Control[] allControls = FlattenHierachy(Page);
        foreach (Control control in allControls)
        {
            if (control.ID != null &&
                ((control is TextBox && ((TextBox)control).Text = "" )
                  || (control is DropDownList && ((DropDownList)control).SelectedIndex != -1 ))
             {
                 if (control.ID.StartsWith("GenInfo_"))
                    GenInfo = true;
                 if (control.ID.StartsWith("EmpInfo_"))
                     EmpInfo = true;

             }
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ah! the control .Text/.SelectedIndex does not work:( though it does look clean

Comment: oops, added the appropriate parens